# JSON how to access an array within a string value in a joomla table in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, joomla

I have searched and I could be asking this question wrong, but here is what I have -

I have JSON data exported from Joomla that has a few key:values such as:

```
....
"images":"{\"image_intro\":\"\",\"float_intro\":\"\",...}", 
"urls":"{\"urla\":null,\"urlatext\":\"\",\"targeta\":\"\",...}", 
"metadata":"{\"tags\":[4,12],\"robots\":\"\",...}", 
....
```

testing script:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index) {
        var product = this;
        var title = product.title;
        var tags = // ?????

        console.log(index + ': ' + title);
        console.log('Metadata: ' + tags); // ????
    });
});
```

The problem is that I need to access the value of things like "image_intro" and "tags". Is there a simple way to retrieve these values without having to write some kind of string search and strip type script?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer two minutes after I asked this question

```
var metadata = product.metadata;
var meta = $.parseJSON(metadata);
console.log(meta.tags);
```